# Unable to install Architexa plugin in STS

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Iam trying to install Architexa plugin in Spring test Suite and get the following error.  Please can some one point what could be the issue ?

[image]

Comment: What version of STS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Tool Suite 3.6.x is [based](http://docs.spring.io/sts/nan/latest/NewAndNoteworthy.html) on Eclipse 4.4x and is not yet supported with the current release of Architexa ([ref](http://www.architexa.com/learn-more/install))

Comment: Please can you let me know a possible time this will be available ?